# C++ Star diamond pattern written to output file becomes jumbled

Tags: c++, formatting, fstream, iostream

I am learning to code in C++ and doing simple beginner exercises. Currently, I am facing a problem where my star diamond pattern output's correctly to the console, but that **same output to the file becomes jumbled**.

This program creates **a * star diamond** based on a row length, and attempts to save that same design to an output file named `output_diamond.txt`.

Any tips or solutions on how to approach an issue like this? I understand the C++ section is very strict, and I made sure to document my code and provide a working re-creatable example.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void pyramid(int rows);
int main() {
    pyramid(8);
    return 0;
}

/*
 * @param int rows
 *
 * Function to output to console a star pyramid
 * based on an amount of rows for a half going
 * vertical. If top half of rows is 8, than the
 * bottom half will be indetical but reverse with
 * a row count of 8.
 */
void pyramid(int rows) {
    ofstream fout;

    fout.open("output_diamond.txt");
    if (fout.is_open()) {
        /* Top Half */
        // Initialize variable for spaces equal to (rows - 1)
        int space = rows - 1;
        // Begin first for loop for top half of diamond
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) { // For 1
            // Begin for loop for spaces
            for (int count = 1; count <= space; count++) { // For 2
                // Output to console a single space
                cout << ' ';
                fout << " ";
            } // End For 2
            // Begin for loop for star/diamond char symbol
            for (int count = 1; count <= (2 * i) - 1; count++) { // For 3
                // Output to console a single *
                cout << '*';
                fout << '*' << endl;
            } // End For 3
            // Before for loop ends output end of line
            cout << endl;
            // Decrement -1 to space
            space--;
        } // End For 1

        /*  Bottom Half */
        // Set value for space variable to 1
        space = 1;
        // Begin first for loop for bottom half of diamond
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows - 1; i++) { // For 1
            // Begin loop for spaces
            for (int count = 1; count <= space; count++) { // For 2
                // Output to console a single space
                cout << ' ';
                fout << ' ';
            } // End For 2
            // Begin for loop for star/diamond char symbol
            for (int count = 1; count <= (2 * (rows - i)) - 1; count++) { // For 3
                // Output to console a single *
                cout << '*';
                fout << '*' << endl;
            } // End For 3
            // Before for loop ends output end of line
            cout << endl;
            // Increment space +1
            space++;
        } // End For 1
    } else {
        cout << "Output file did not open!" << endl;
        assert(fout);
    }
    // End
}
```

**Console Output**

```
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
***************
 *************
  ***********
   *********
    *******
     *****
      ***
       *
```

**Sample Text File Output**

```
       *
      *
*
*
     *
*
*
*
*
    *
*
*
*
*
*
*
   *
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: You're not printing the same thing, so why would you expect them to produce the same result? You're writing a lot of `endl`s into fout but not cout.

Comment: You are using `fout << '*' << endl;` when the corresponding console output is `cout << '*';` - those two are not the same

Comment: Why are you simultaneously outputting different things to the standard output and to the file? Your logic is hard to follow. To simplify things, why don't you write everything to a `std::stringstream`, whose contents you can then print to the standard output or a file, without repeating yourself?

Comment: I'd recommend you extract and consoldidate  your _"business logic"_ to a function that takes a `std::ostream&` as a parameter, and call it either with `std::cout` or a `std::ofstream&` instance.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I did not notice that. Was able to fix with your guys help and @John Kugelman

Comment: The comment by @πάνταῥεῖ is exactly how this problem should be solved.  Create a function that takes a `std::ostream&`, write the code to that `ostream`, and simply pass the stream type as a parameter.

Comment: @Raymond _"May I ask what the close (2) means under my thread, and why someone would click that? I am unfamiliar with what that is."_ That means that two people voted to close your question so far. Me was one of them, because you missed to provide a [mcve] and any debugging efforts with your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry to upset you. Will remember that.

Comment: @Raymond I am not _upset_. We're all just humans and prone to erroneous behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The practical solution is to take what works and generalize it.  What works is the output generated by `std::cout`, thus all that is required is to write a function that takes a stream and does exactly what `std::cout` is doing.

The way to do that is to realize that `std::ostream` is the base class for the output streams, thus all that is needed is to use polymorphism and write a function that takes a reference to a `std::ostream`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void pyramid(int rows, std::ostream& );

int main() 
{
    // use regular cout
    std::cout << "Using cout \n\n";
    pyramid(8, std::cout);

    // try file printing
    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open("output_diamond.txt");
    pyramid(8, fout);

    // try printing to a string stream
    std::cout << "\n\nUsing ostringstream \n\n";
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    pyramid(8, ostrm);
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << ostrm.str();
    return 0;
}

void pyramid(int rows, std::ostream& sout) 
{
    int space = rows - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) { 
        for (int count = 1; count <= space; count++) { 
            sout << ' ';
        } 
        for (int count = 1; count <= (2 * i) - 1; count++) { 
            sout << '*';
        } 
        sout << endl;
        space--;
    } 
    space = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows - 1; i++) { 
        for (int count = 1; count <= space; count++) { 
            sout << ' ';
        } 
        for (int count = 1; count <= (2 * (rows - i)) - 1; count++) { 
            sout << '*';
        } 
        sout << endl;
        space++;
    }
}
```

[Live Example showing std::cout and std::ostringstream](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee3131baf2acdcb)

And here is the output from the file:

```
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
***************
 *************
  ***********
   *********
    *******
     *****
      ***
       *
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it is so nice of you to do this. Because literally, I was just building the method you suggested and had just started understanding it. And it feels good to know mine is exactly how you did yours. So I am actually learning.

Answer (score 2):

Your `cout` and `fout` lines should always come in pairs and should always be identical.

```
// Output to console a single *
cout << '*';
fout << '*' << endl;
```

Get rid of the `<< endl`. This occurs in two places.

```
// Before for loop ends output end of line
cout << endl;
```

Add `fout << endl;`. This also occurs twice.